# How do I determine size of ANSI terminal?

Tags: terminal, language-agnostic, ansi-escape

Standard input and output are connected to a terminal that implements ANSI escape sequences, but is of unknown dimensions.

I need to know how big the terminal so to facilitate drawing a full-screen text UI on it. How can I get the size?

The correct size is not loaded into environment variables. I cannot use TIOCGETS; the the call would return success but the values are not correct -- the kernel doesn't know the size either.

There are lots and lots of answers searching stackoverflow, but they all depend on the OS providing the answer one way or anther; but this time that is not true.

The best clue I can find is the DSR command which returns the current cursor position; but there's no move to bottom/right command.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termcap-1.3/html_mono/termcap.html#SEC25 :: "co" and "li"

Comment: OP already indicated that doesn't work.

Comment: @wildplasser: ansi doesn't have capacities co and li.

Comment: Ok, Ok. I stand corrected. Let's assume 80*24 then, for crippled terminals (and maybe allow an override using command line flags on the client side)

Comment: OP needs clarification on ANSI sequences; `resize` is a good example for starting that, since it does what OP actually needs to know.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [`resize`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/resize.html) program does this by moving the cursor to a very large column and row; the terminal moves as far as it can, e.g.,

```
CUP 999 999
```

Then `resize` asks where the cursor *is*:

```
DSR 6
```

The terminal replies with the actual cursor position (i.e., the cursor position report `CPR`), from which `resize` knows the terminal's size: the cursor is on the lower-right corner.

That's all done using standard ([ECMA-48](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm) / VT100) escape sequences.  In [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) (which should apply to your "ANSI" terminal)

```
CSI Ps n  Device Status Report (DSR).
            Ps = 6  -> Report Cursor Position (CPR) [row;column].
          Result is CSI r ; c R
```